# Have faulty mobility equip that drains battery overnight. Can't get it fixed for next two weeks

Tags: battery

I live in a condo with no electrical outlet access in garage where car is parked, so trickle charge or plug-in starter/charger not an option. The faulty equipment that can't be fixed till after holidays drains the battery overnight.  Looking for temporary fix till then.  Driving around local roads at 35-45 mph for 30 minutes has not been sufficient to prevent battery from draining down to non-start level.  No local roads to go at higher speed.  Only thing that has worked is to run car at around 2000 RPM at idle for an hour - Battery will start car after 12 hours so twice per day recharge needed.  Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the fuses to the faulty equipment.

Comment: [Auxiliary jump start battery ?](https://www.napaonline.com/en/p/BK_JS1000A). Charge that in house, use at startup?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How accessible is the power connection for the equipment? If you can disconnect it once you're done for the day, then reconnect it before you get going in the morning, it should give you what you're looking for.